# Is "Like what you see?" a correct sentence?

Tags: questions

On Windows 10 start screen, for some time the default is pictures with subtitles. One of them "Like what you see?"

However I think in correct English we should ask "Do you like what you see?"

Am I wrong? Or is this a mistake of Microsoft engineers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In informal speech and writing, we often can omit preceding phrases such as ''Did you", "Do you", "Have you", "Are you", etc. `Like what you see?` is fine. The question mark tells the reader it is a question, and he or she can imagine "Do you... " at the beginning. Other examples: Want some more? Had enough? Seen enough? Heard enough? Finished? Happy? Everything all right?.

Comment: The technical name for this is [left-edge ellipsis](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/english-language-and-linguistics/article/leftedge-deletion-in-english-and-subject-omission-in-diaries1/8565903575654D65D2FCC6A6AAC93EAF).

Answer (score 2):

It is common in English to leave some words out of a spoken or written sentence, the idea being that those words are understood to be there. If you were looking at a picture with someone standing next to you, especially someone that you knew fairly well, "Like what you see?" would be a grammatically correct sentence. Microsoft is using that form, possibly to make it seem casual and personal for their advertisement.